# Objective C -- how to find where error occurs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdb

I am receiving a message from GDB as follows on the console:

```
2011-03-06 12:31:01.303 myProgram[3830:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(): release of previously deallocated object (0x61472a0) ignored
```

How do I find which line in the program (which I assume is referenced by [3830:207] was attempting the release?

Comment: It's not as much "Which line attempted the release" than "Which line deallocated the object that is being release again" that you should try to find.

Comment: That's a given. However, I need to find out which object is a problem and this is my only clue. Either the initial deallocate is wrong or the second one is. I only have a clue as to the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Allocations Instrument against your app.

In particular, "flip " the allocations instrument over and turn on zombie detection & track retain/release events.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it depends on where you are in your execution. If you can figure out what class is responsible, it'll be easier to pinpoint the error. The 207 is referencing a line number; I can't find a reference to the 3830 in the [GDB reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

Comment: I'm not sure that's a line number. 207 appears whenever I get an error or nslog as in the following: 2011-03-06 13:38:15.466 myProgram[3946:207] Error 1 preparing story record for update which is an error message I display in the app when a sqlite statement fails. This nslog comes in line 700 or so of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this quick GDB tutorial will help:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/gdb-tutorial/